# How do I put TestConfiguration in an abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some Spring tests that all define the same test configuration:

```
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public EmployeeClient employeeClient(MockMvc mockMvc) {
            return new EmployeeClient(mockMvc);
        }
    }
```

To reduce replication I put that code into an abstract class and had each test extend that abstract class. However, this threw Spring unresolved dependencies - it couldn't resolve `EmployeeClient`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to make your Test class use multiple configuration files.

```
@Configuration
class CommonBeans {
}

@Configuration
class SpecificBeans {
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CommonBeans.class, SpecificBeans.class}) 
public class MyAppTest {
  ------
}
```

---

In your test package if you are creating a configuration using @TestConfiguration instead of @Configuration then you have to use @Import annotation to make use of that.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestBeans {
    
}

@Import(TestBeans.class)
public class MyAppTest {
      ------
}
```

Comment: Thanks the import worked. Should I be using ```@Configuration``` rather than ```@TestConfiguration``` though?

Comment: It totally depends on your requirement, just understand the distinction between all of them and make your decision. if any of your class is annotated with @SpringBootTest then it will automatically scan and create beans for all Configuration classes but you have to explicitly do Import of TestConfiguration . You can google to understand even further.

Comment: Import configuration does not work the same as Spring autodetecting TestConfiguration. (for example when using named beans, using import complains that the bean with the same name is already defined, but TestConfiguration simply overwrites the already defined config, and does not give an error)